# How to Write a recursive function to print all permutations of a given string without for loop

Tags: python

i wrote a program that give me all permutations of a given string , but i am searching if there is any way to make it recursive function with no ( for / while ) loops

here is my code (found in another site) :

```
def permutation(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return []
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return [lst]

    l = []

    for i in range(len(lst)):
        m = lst[i]

        remLst = lst[:i] + lst[i + 1:]

        for p in permutation(remLst):
            l.append([m] + p)
    return l
```

Comment: It already is a recursive function; it calls itself.

Comment: i just want it without for / while loop